# R refer to vector to create a new column in a Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I need to write a Function in R that extracts segments of strings from a column in a matrix and replaces created a new column with a number found refers to a vector and giving the number.

In the Matrix's Column 0, There is s string such as "ind1.pt1", "ind2.pt1" ,,, "ind1.pt2". I want to extract the "pt_" string and refer to a vector where I have the "pt-" strings referring to an ID number. I want a new column in the matrix with the specific ID for the "pt-" string.

Matrix dimensions = 49140 by 79
Vector Lenghth = 819

```
> DIDconcat7[1:10,0:2]
       info var2
ind1.pt1      1   NA
ind2.pt1  10009   NA
ind3.pt1     60   NA
ind4.pt1     60   NA
ind5.pt1     60   NA
ind6.pt1     60   NA
ind7.pt1     24   NA
ind8.pt1     60   NA
ind9.pt1     60   NA
ind10.pt1    60   NA 

> ID[1:10]
  pt1   pt2   pt3   pt4   pt5   pt6   pt7   pt8   pt9  pt10 
10009 10017 10025 10041 10059 10067 10075 10083 10091 10116
```

Desired Output would be:

```
           info ID
ind1.pt1      1   10009 
ind2.pt1  10009   10009 
ind3.pt1     60   10009 
ind4.pt1     60   10009 
ind5.pt1     60   10009 
ind6.pt1     60   10009 
ind7.pt1     24   10009 
ind8.pt1     60   10009 
ind9.pt1     60   10009 
ind10.pt1    60   10009 
....
ind1.pt2    60   10017
ind1.pt3    60   10025
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with the desired output.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]!

Comment: hope I've done what you asked, excuse me being a beginner to R and Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
ID <- c(10009, 10017, 10025, 10041, 10059, 10067, 10075, 10083, 10091, 10116) 
names(ID) <- paste0("pt", 1:10)
ID

DIDconcat <- data.frame(info=sample(20:99, 10), 
   row.names = paste0("ind", 1:10, ".pt", rep(1:3, times=c(3, 5, 2))))
DIDconcat
rownames(DIDconcat)
IDind <- sub("^.*\\.", "", rownames(DIDconcat))
DIDconcat$ID <- ID[IDind]
DIDconcat
```

This is using `sub()` to manipulate the rownames of your dataframe `rownames(DIDconcat)`. After this you can use the result as index for `ID`: `DIDconcat$ID <- ID[result]`
The essential part in one line:

```
DIDconcat$ID <- ID[sub("^.*\\.", "", rownames(DIDconcat))]
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I do this for the whole matrix of 49140 rows, please?

Comment: My solution **not** depends on the number of rows of your dataframe DIDconcat.